# parsing webpage using python

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to parse a webpage (forums.macrumors.com) and get a list of all the threads posted.

So I have got this so far:

```
import urllib2 
import re

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
address = "http://forums.macrumors.com/forums/os/"                         
website = urllib2.urlopen(address) 
website_html = website.read() 
text = urllib2.urlopen(address).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
```

Now the webpage source has this code at the start of each thread:

```
<li id="thread-1880" class="discussionListItem visible sticky WikiPost  "   
data-author="ABCD">
```

How do I parse this so I can then get to the thread link within this li tag? Thanks for the help.

Comment: See: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from your code here, you have the `soup` object which contains the `BeautifulSoup` object of your html. The question is what part of that tag you're looking for is static? Is the `id` always the same? the `class`?

Finding by the `id`:

```
my_li = soup.find('li', {'id': 'thread-1880'})
```

Finding by the `class`:

```
my_li = soup.find('li', {'class': 'discussionListItem visible sticky WikiPost  "})
```

Ideally you would figure out the unique class you can check for and use that instead of a list of classes.

if you are expecting an `a` tag inside of this object, you can do this to check:

```
if my_li and my_li.a:
    print my_li.a.attrs.get('href')
```

I always recommend checking though, because if the `my_li` ends up being `None` or there is no `a` inside of it, your code will fail.

For more details, check out the BeautifulSoup documentation
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: the thread would not be static but I just want to get all the thread-xxxx that are on that page.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here would be to use [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and to get the `a` elements inside the `h3` with `class="title"` inside the `div` with `class="titleText"` inside the `li` element having the `id` attribute starting with "thread":

```
for link in soup.select("div.discussionList li[id^=thread] div.titleText h3.title a[href]"):
    print link["href"]
```

You can tweak the selector further, but this should give you a good starting point.